# List box Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net

I looked around for an answer for this, but theres nothing on here that helps this issue.

I'm trying to add an item to a listbox from a List.

Variables:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int id = 0;
    public static string[] itemname;
    public static int amount = 0;
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Add to list box.

```
            id++;
            itemname[id] = "foo";
            _items.Add(itemname[id]);
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = _items;
            using (StreamWriter writer
                = new StreamWriter(itemname[id]))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(id);
            }
```

I used this http://www.dotnetperls.com/listbox to learn how to add to a listbox.

Picture of the UI http://puu.sh/h7qim/c5597d91e5.png

Comment: And what problem are you having with your code to add to a list box?

Comment: In the title "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: What line is the error occuring on?

Comment: _items.Add(itemname[id]);

Comment: Where exactly have you instatiated your variables?

Comment: Well, then either `_items` is null or `itemname` is null.  Have you tried using a debugger to see which it is?

Comment: When the class starts, see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not instantiated `itemname`. You need to do this (3 is just a random number):

```
public static string[] itemname = new string[3];
```

If you didn't do this, you should have received the error on this line:

```
itemname[id] = "foo";
```